# リソースのjsonファイルを読み込む

Tags: swift

リソースのjsonファイルを読み込みたいのですが出来ずに困っています。

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jdata", ofType:"json")
    let handle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: path!)
    let data = handle?.readDataToEndOfFile()

    do{
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!)
        print(json)
    }catch{print("error")}
```

とした場合、errorと表示されます。

do以前で宣言が間違っているのでしょうか？

もし、そうでしたらどう訂正したら良いのか教えて頂けませんか？
よろしくお願いします。

*****以下、コメントから編集した箇所*****

*****追記１*****

```
{
   "id":"String"
}
```

があるとすると、「"」のはずが「”」で区切られていたようで全てのデータの記号を確認して書式通りに変更したところ、エラーが消えました。

ありがとうございました。

＊＊＊＊＊追記２＊＊＊＊＊

コメント頂きましたエラー出力です。
データ数は２３です。

***Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 23." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 23.}***

character=データ数なんですね。
ご指摘とエラー潰しで理解できました。

重ね重ねありがとうございます。

Comment: 当初EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONが発生したと書かれていたようですが、それについては解決して、`do-catch`内は実行されて、その結果として`print("error")`により「**error**と表示」されていると言うことでよろしいでしょうか。だとしたらcatchした`error`の中身を表示してやればもう少し情報がわかるはずです。`print("error")`を`print(error)`に変更したらどんな内容が出力されますか?

Comment: 早い反応ありがとうございます。
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONにつきましては自己解決しました。
原因は、そもそも違うプロジェクトで記述をしていました完全な注意不足でお恥ずかしい限りです><

errorで出力させた結果以下の出力を確認しました。

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 2." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 2.**}

と表示されました。これはどういった意味になるのでしょうか・・・

Comment: ファイルの内容が正しいJSONになっていないと言うことです。 **around character 2** とあるからJSONデータの２文字目付近、 **No string key for value in object** と言うのは「JSONオブジェクトのはずなのに、キーに当たる場所に文字列が来てないよ」と言う事です。JSONオブジェクトは`{key: value,...}`の形をしていますが、`key`の部分は必ず`"`に囲まれたJSON文字列の形式になっていないといけません。jdata.jsonの中身が正しいJSON形式になっているか確認してみてください。(JavaScriptとして正しくても、正しいJSONになるとは限りません。)

Comment: ありがとうざいます！
コンソールのエラーが消えました。
出力されたのが{
    1 = "\U96f7";
}
が表示されたのですが,この文字を漢字で表示するにはどうしたらいいですか？？

Comment: jsonにまつわるエラーでこのスレッドを見つけた読者の方は、どのように「エラーが消えました」のかが全くわからないのではないでしょうか。できればコメントでお寄せくださった情報をご質問に盛り込むようにしてご質問内容を編集してください。StackOverflowのようなQ&Aサイトとしては、AのないQだけがどんどん溜まっていくというのは良くない状態です。今後同じことで悩んでいる(未来の)読者を助けられるようなQ&Aを作り上げることにご協力ください。

Comment: おっしゃる通りですね、すみません、早速載せます。夜分遅いのに解決へのヒントありがとうざいました。

Comment: 追記してくださった内容は、回答の方にご記載頂きたい内容ですね。ご質問の方には「その問題を解決するために必要な情報」…この問題の場合ですと`print(error)`で出力した情報(コメントと重複することになりますが)を追記していただきたかったのですが…。解決へのヒントよりお願いの方が多くなって恐縮ですが、(過去のご質問を含め)解決方法は回答として投稿していただくよう、またその回答を承認していただく(こちらは少し時間が要るようですが)ようお願いします。

Comment: 気配り足らずすみません。早速追記します。