# Bundleについて

Tags: swift, ios

Bundleについて質問です。

他サイトで閲覧して疑問に感じたので質問させていただきました。

Bundleディレクトリを作ることによって得られるメリットは具体的にどんなことがありますか？？

また、Bundleディレクトリを使うのが望ましい場合はどんな時ですか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「Bundleディレクトリ」は、リソース（ボタンなどのイメージファイル、効果音などのサウンドファイル等々アプリを構成する実行ファイル以外のファイル）を置く場所で、必須なものです。

[リソースのjsonファイルを読み込む](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/32470/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AEjson%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80)

こちらの質問者さんの質問で、JSONファイルをリソースから読み込むプログラムが載っています。チュートリアルのプログラムでは、よくあるパターンですが、じっさいのアプリでは、そういうことはほとんどないでしょう。ネットワーク経由で、サーバからJSONファイルをダウンロードするとか、ユーザが新規に作成するとかいう形が、ふつうではないでしょうか？
JSONファイル、データベース、種々のドキュメントファイルは、`Documents`フォルダに保存することになっています。このフォルダ（ディレクトリ）のURL取得は、次のコードで行います。

```
let documentDirectories = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
print(documentDirectories[0])
```

返り値が、URLの配列になっていることに、気をつけてください。配列といっても、ほとんどの環境では、要素が一つだけで、`0`番目の要素から取得します。

Comment: なるほど、そういうことなんですね。Bundleディレクトリ=リソースディレクトリ(画像・効果音等)という理解で今後頑張ります。